# Не удается добавить изображение через админ панель Django

Tags: python, django

При попытке добавить изображение, выдает вот такую ошибку. Пробовал разные форматы и т.д. Изображения не битые. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так какие форматы пробовали-то?

Comment: png, jpg, jpeg. под мои задачи мне эти в принципе форматы подойдут. в settings.py настройки на media выставил, в модели использую imagefield

Comment: Pillow не забыли установить?

Comment: Pillow стоит, в чем проблема не понимаю, делал по видео уроку. Кто объяснял на видео, танцы с бубном не устраивал, просто выбрал картинку и она залилась

Comment: Сам нашёл решение. Помогло снести библиотеку Pillow и установить Pillow самой последней версии